# Enviar variables a SP con foreach

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo un metodo que lee de una tabla(X) 3 valores y se los envia a un StoreProceduce tantas veces como registros tenga la tabla(x)

entonces lo q hago es lo siguiente:

```
foreach (var item in resultado)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.Id;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Valor", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = item.Valor;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

El problema es que me da un error:

> La función o el procedimiento sp_UPDATE tiene demasiados argumentos.

Comment: Desde el SP solo espero estos tres parametros y del mismo tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta asi :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Valor", SqlDbType.Decimal)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime)

foreach (var item in resultado)
{
    cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = item.Id;
    cmd.Parameters["@Valor"].Value = item.Valor;
    cmd.Parameters["@LastUpdate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ya lo resolví.
solo tuve que agregar la siguiente linea para que se "Limpie" la colección de parámetros. (`cmd.Parameters.Clear();`)
quedando Así, funcionando perfecto.

```
            foreach (var item in resultado)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();//Esto soliciono mi problema
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item.Id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Valor", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = item.Valor;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Más pareciera que la solución fue poner el `ExecuteNonQuery` dentro del foreach...

Comment: @Lamak sí, pero también creo que limpiar la lista de parámetros influyó ya que en cada iteración del `foreach` se agregan 3 parámetros y si no se limpian se van agregando al comando, es por eso del mensaje "*La función o el procedimiento sp_UPDATE tiene demasiados argumentos.*"

Comment: Asi es. el cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); lo meti dentro del Foreach y Parametrers.Clear tambien fu fundamenta.
Muchas gracias a todos